# What other Adapters can I use for ListView?

Tags: android

I am currently using SimpleAdapter for my ListView. I just want to know if are there any adapters I can use to display from JSON objects.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CheckAttendanceActivity.this, studentList, R.layout.list_students, new String[]{Tags.getIDNO(), Tags.getREMARK(), Tags.getFULLNAME()}, new int[]{R.id.idno, R.id.remark, R.id.fullname}) {
                        @Override
                        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                            if (convertView == null) {
                                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(CheckAttendanceActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.list_students, parent, false);
                            }

                            TextView fullname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
                            TextView idno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idno);
                            TextView remark = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remark);

                            HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);
                            if(obj.get("remark").equals("present")) {
                                convertView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPresent));
                                fullname.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            }
                            else if(obj.get("remark").equals("late")) {
                                convertView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorLate));
                                fullname.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            }
                            else {
                                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                fullname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            }

                            fullname.setText(obj.get("fullname").toString());
                            idno.setText(obj.get("idno").toString());
                            remark.setText(obj.get("remark").toString());


                            return convertView;
                        }
                    };
```

studentList is `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()` and inside it I am putting some `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>()` sample inside the map is

```
map.put("idno", "01");
map.put("remark", "absent");
map.put("fullname", "John");

studentList.add(map);
```

Any other adapters I can use for this? Any sample?

Comment: Recycler view are best and their adapter are really fast in displaying the results.

Comment: RecyclerView is best because it forces you to use the ViewHolder pattern (re-use of cells as you scroll up and down, no longer needing to call findViewById over and over...), supports animations, and abstracts away the container of the List (GridLayoutManager, LinearLayoutManager) so you can swap this on the fly. Just wanted to leave a better response of RecyclerView vs. ListView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend BaseAdapter like so;

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private List<Student> students;

        public MyAdapter(List<Student> students, Context context) {
            this.students = students;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return students.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return students.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            //Similar to SimpleAdapter's getView()
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_students, viewGroup, false);
            }

            //Bind views
            TextView fullname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
            TextView idno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idno);
            TextView remark = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remark);

            Student student = (Student) getItem(i);

            fullname.setText(student.getName());
            idno.setText(String.valueOf(student.getIdno()));
            remark.setText(student.getRemark());

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Model for student

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int idno;
    private String remark;

    public Student(String name, int idno, String remark) {
        this.name = name;
        this.idno = idno;
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getIdno() {
        return idno;
    }

    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }
}
```

Setting the adapter inside your activity

```
public void setupList(ListView listView) {

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    students.add(new Student("aaa", 12, "bad"));
    students.add(new Student("bbb", 14, "good"));

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(students, this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

That said, you should consider using `RecyclerView` because it is better than `ListView` in every way.

Comment: I tried using this but it isn't displaying the texts. The number of items are correct though. The display is the only lacking. Sorry, I'm still a noob to Android.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll try recyclerview rather. Thanks!

Comment: see edit. All you needed to do was to bind the `TextView`s