# Display information in listview (Estimote Beacon)

Tags: android, listview, estimote

So I've been trying to use the estimote beacon and have been learning how to use it with the help of their tutorials... 
But towards the end, they say that one needs to use a display a hashmap in a listview...
here's the code: 
    private static final Map> PLACES_BY_BEACONS;

```
// TODO: replace "<major>:<minor>" strings to match your own beacons.
static {
    Map<String, List<String>> placesByBeacons = new HashMap<>();
    placesByBeacons.put("29098:1493", new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Heavenly Sandwiches");
        // read as: "Heavenly Sandwiches" is closest
        // to the beacon with major 22504 and minor 48827
        add("Green & Green Salads");
        // "Green & Green Salads" is the next closest
        add("Mini Panini");
        // "Mini Panini" is the furthest away
    }});
    placesByBeacons.put("52504:13020", new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Mini Panini");
        add("Green & Green Salads");
        add("Heavenly Sandwiches");
    }});
    PLACES_BY_BEACONS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(placesByBeacons);
}

private List<String> placesNearBeacon(Beacon beacon) {
    String beaconKey = String.format("%d:%d", beacon.getMajor(), beacon.getMinor());
    if (PLACES_BY_BEACONS.containsKey(beaconKey)) {
        return PLACES_BY_BEACONS.get(beaconKey);
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}



private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private Region region;
ListView lv;

 Button reserveButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    reserveButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                Beacon nearestBeacon = list.get(0);
                List<String> places = placesNearBeacon(nearestBeacon);
                // TODO: update the UI here
                Log.d("Airport", "Nearest places: " + places);
            }
        }
    });


    region = new Region("ranged region",
            UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), null, null);






    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Message your friends", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

So my question is how do I display all that is in the placesByBeacons object in my UI (Listview) which is referred to by lv in the code.

Comment: You are probably looking for a `ListView` tutorial here...?

Comment: It's not a listview tutorial I'm looking for. I tried to put it up using an array adapter but it didn't work. So I need some other code...

Comment: Have you tried `BaseAdapter`? Take a look at sample implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495312/what-other-adapters-can-i-use-for-listview/35495669#35495669

Comment: What do you need exactly... Which part are you stuck in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a `ListView` to your layout.
2. Put this code in `onCreate`:

   ```
   ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
   final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
           this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

   This takes the list view from your layout and sets it up with an adapter for a collection of strings, which is exactly what `places` are. (It uses an Android-predefined layout for the items on the list view, [which is actually just a `TextView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml).)

   Note the `R.id.listView`, i.e., this code assumes that the `ListView` you added in step 1 has ID `listView`.
3. Just below the "TODO: update the UI here," add:

   ```
   adapter.clear();
   adapter.addAll(places);
   ```

   This replaces the data backing the list view with the most fresh data generated from beacon ranging results.